# Eclipse CDT debugger keeps opening header and assembly files

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I try to use the Eclipse debugger it opens all functions and constructors I use, and for files without sources it opens something called Dissasembly, this makes it unusable for code which uses lots of std functions. How can I disable the opening of other files while debugging C++? Can it be set to ask if I want to view a method or constructor? Is this a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: Don't "step into" functions you don't want to look at - just "step over".  If you accidentally step into a function you don't want to look at, most debuggers have a "step out" function too.

Comment: @MartinBonner I thought "step over" doesn't execute the line you're stepping over.

Comment: @MartinBonner That fixed it, could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't "step into" functions you don't want to look at - just "step over". If you accidentally step into a function you don't want to look at, most debuggers have a "step out" function too.

To be clear:  "step over" means "execute (all) the function call(s) on this line, and move onto the next line".  It is the opposite of "step into" which goes inside each function (one by one if there are more than one).

"Step over" does not mean "do not execute this line and skip to the next one".  There is usually a capability to do that (or go back to re-execute some code you have already executed), but that is a hack for when you can see that a call is out of order.